# SSAS new calculated member to display summary info

Tags: date, calendar, ssas, mdx

I am facing an issue that looks trivial to me but that cannot solve for days now... 
My cube has mainly one DimDate dimension (to simplify my issue): 
in the dim date, I have two hierarchies:
one standard (Time) that decompose the date in Date, Month, Quarter and Year
One (Trimester Time) that decompose the date in Date, Month, Trimester (one third of a year) and Year.
on my fact table I have for each day a purchase Orders (PO) and a measure integer (0 or 1) that indicate that the PO is active.
When browsing on each date I am able to see how much PO are active (Sum).

As you can expect, when I am looking at the figures for the month... I have the sum for each day... which is obviously not what I am expecting. I am trying to find that number that where open on the very last day of that period.

I then created several attributes to the dimDate: 
Is Last Day Of Calendar Qtr
Is Last Day Of Calendar Trimester
Is Last Day Of Calendar Month
Is Last Day Of Calendar Year

Then I created a new calculated member that is like that:

```
    CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MyMeasures]
 AS CASE
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarYear] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarQtr] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Qtr].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarMonth] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[Date] then
        [Measures].[Active]
    ELSE NULL
END, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Duration';
```

this was working fine up until I got requested to extend the measure for both hierarchies. 
I then did update the member with the following:

```
    CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MyMeasures]
 AS CASE
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarYear] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarQtr] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Qtr].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarMonth] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[Date] then
        [Measures].[Active]

    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[CalendarYear] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[Calendar Year Trimester] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Trimester].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[CalendarMonth] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[Date] then
        [Measures].[Active]

    ELSE NULL
END, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Duration';
```

their must be something that is conceptualy wrong in my though process, but I cannot get it...
can someone help me?

as a result I get the bellow results in Excel:

[with the time hierarchy, it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4bzk.jpg)

[with the trimester hierarchy, it shows only 3rd trimester...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pShNZ.jpg)

Comment: what result do you get from this measure? or do you get an exception?

Comment: Hi whytheq,
I have amended my question so that you can see the result.... 
I have no exception. when no dimension is selected and just the fact is selected, I have no result when I would have excepted a NULL... 
Remark: My trimester hierarchy is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Are these the only levels in `[Dim Date].[Time]`?

```
[Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarYear]
[Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarQtr]
[Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarMonth] 
[Dim Date].[Time].[Date]
```

If they are all the levels of the hierarchy then your `CASE` statement will never get to the new options you've added because one of the above 4 will always be true.

Comment: Hi whytheq, yes, these are my only levels in my dimension... could you explain why?
what I would like to achieve is that based on the selected dimension, I would calculate the member differently, and as of today I cannot figure out if it is possible, reasonable, a common practice or simply a stupidity... :)

Comment: @Gaugo thing is, even if in a select a particular level has not been selected e.g say your select does not contain any of those 4, behind the scenes I think a default will have been used - and will be the currentmember. I will try to illustrate via AdvWrks

Comment: I think I understand your point.... my findings for today is: as the hierarchies are using the same members (the level "Year" will be used careless what hierarchy is used..). What I do not understand is why, do I only see Trimester 3..... remark: if I swap the two blocks of case ("time" and "time trimester") then, I see all the trimester but only the last quarter...

Comment: @Gaugo I believe every hierarchy in your cube will have a currentmember even if only 1 hierarchy is in your select: these will generally be the All member of each.

Answer (score 0):

@whytheQ has identified a problem in the last comment: because you're trying to cater for two hierarchies, you need to react to the situation where one (or both) of the hierarchies are "not in use".  If *both* hierarchies are "in use", all bets are off - I'm not sure I'd even try to cater for that situation; probably I'd just "give up" and fall back to a NULL value.

How about trying this?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MyMeasures]
 AS

 -- Is Time hierarchy current member "ALL" level?
 CASE WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].Levels(0)
 THEN
    -- Not interested in Time hierarchy - see if we need to do anything interesting on Time Trimester hierarchy
    CASE 
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[CalendarYear] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[Calendar Year Trimester] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Trimester].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[CalendarMonth] then
        ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y])
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[Date] then
        [Measures].[Active]
    ELSE
        -- Time Trimester All - neither hierarchy in use: maybe show measure from last date ever here, instead of NULL?
        NULL
    END
ELSE
     CASE
        WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarYear] then
            ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12])
        WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarQtr] then
            ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Qtr].&[Y])
        WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarMonth] then
            ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y])
        WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[Date] then
            [Measures].[Active]
        -- No need for ELSE here if all levels of [Time] are covered
    END
END
, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Duration';
```

You might get better performance (or more clarity) by using SCOPE to only invoke this logic if the .CurrentMember in either [Time] or [Time Trimester] hierarchy is NOT All or the leaf (Date) level.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using the bellow statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level.Ordinal=0 THEN 
        NULL
    WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level.Ordinal<>0 THEN 

        CASE WHEN [Dim Date].[Time].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time].[CalendarQtr] then
                ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Qtr].&[Y])
             WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[Calendar Year Trimester] then
                ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Calendar Trimester].&[Y])

             WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[CalendarYear] then
                iif(isempty(([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12])),1,([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y],[Dim Date].[Month Of Year].&[12]))
             WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[CalendarMonth] then
                ([Measures].[Active],[Dim Date].[Is Last Day Of Month].&[Y])
             WHEN [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].currentMember.Level is [Dim Date].[Time Trimester].[Date] then
                [Measures].[Active]
         END

    ELSE NULL
    END
```

I must admit that I am not yet happy with the final statement but at least this issue is solved....

O